# How to get the current page URL in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add the current page URL into my PayPal button code.  Here's the line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]; . '">
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/username/public_html/folder/otherfolder/paypal/package.php on line 14

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `; .` is the problem...

Comment: You have ended the expression with `;`. Just as PHP tells you, the `.` is *unexpected* at the beginning of the next expression. The error message here is quite informative and useful.

Comment: @Wrikken Just the `;` actually ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: If we're going to be pedantic, the combination is the problem: `$string = 'bla'.'blah';` does not cause a syntax error, but neither does `$string = 'bar';'blah';` (but granted, probably unwanted results / a logical error) :P

Comment: @Wrikken You have a point there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a semi-colon `;` after the closing bracket.

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . '">
```